# Join on a joined model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize as an ORM with a postreSQL database.
Simple joins are quite easy to use with the `include` attribute, but what if I need to join a model from one that was also joined?
I tried to add an `include` attribute in the first one, but it did not work.

Is there a standard way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a nested include should be the way to do it:

```
Model.findAll({ include: { model: SomeModel, include: [ SomeOtherModel ]}})
```

Perhaps you are using an old version - it was introduced late in 2.0 I think